# Telerik RadgridView - making columns invisible based on criteria

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm in the process of converting standard ASP.NET Gridviews to Telerik RadGridViews.  One important aspect of this for some of the grids is making certain template columns not visible to the user based on some criteria.  These template columns were asp:Template (button) columns on the old grids and will be telerik:Gridbutton columns on the new RadGridviews

The process of hiding the button on the old grids was done via the rowDataBound method.  In other words, in the RowDataBound method there was code like

**if view state variable = some value, set enabled/visible property off for the button template column.**

As there is no RowDataBound method for RadGridviews, is there a way to accomplish the same thing in RadGridViews, either during retrieval, or post retrieval?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the below code snippet in `PreRender` RadGrid event to hide the columns

ASPX

```
    <telerik:radgrid id="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="btn_column"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
    </Columns>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    rgCards.MasterTableView.GetColumn("btn_column").Visible = false;    // set this based on your 'view state variable = some value'
{
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the `OnItemDataBound` RadGrid event (Fired after an item is databound to the RadGrid control) to show/ hide for each row.

ASPX

```
    <telerik:radgrid id="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
```

CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
    { 
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
        item["btn_column"].Visible = false;    // set this based on your 'view state variable = some value'
    } 
}
```

Further the `OnItemCreated` event (Fired on the server when an item in the RadGrid control is created) also can be made use of to achieve similar results as well.

Refer Telerik RadGrid Documentation for in-depth features - [RadGrid Overview](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/overview)